# Div with transparent gap inside border

Tags: css, border, transparency, css-shapes

I've got a div of varying size that needs to have a transparent area followed by a white border as seen in this screenshot:

[image: gap between border and background]

I have no problem getting the red transparency and shape correct, but am at a loss on how to get the transparent area followed by the white border. How can I do this?

Comment: Add an fixed height, rgb background and box-shadow for the white line. I will make a jsfiddle soon ;) Sorry...box shadow doenst work you need to use nested div

Comment: can u show us ur code?

Comment: _I have no problem getting the red transparency and shape correct_... show us the code so that someone could expand upon it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You make a **gap between the background colour and border** with :

- one element.
- a transparent border to make the transparent gap between the box-shadow and the background.
- `background-clip:padding-box;` to clip the background inside the transparent border (otherwise the background colour would overflow and appear through the transparent border, [more info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)).
- a `box-shadow` with spread-radius for the outer line.

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .7);
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #fff;  
}

/** FOR THE DEMO **/
body {background: url('https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8760/17195790401_ceeeafcddb_o.jpg');background-size: cover;}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Link to [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sabipu/0qouvrwn/)

```
div{
    background: #f00;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
div:before{
    content: '';
    top: -5px;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Radial gradients can be used too:

```css
#test {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(circle at 120px center, 
      rgba(255, 0, 0, .5) 100px,
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 100px,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 105px,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) 105px,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) 110px,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 110px
    ),
    url(http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1280-960-5.jpg) center/cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Radial gradients have added advantage. For example you can draw ellipses instead of circles, add more borders and create more sophisticated patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I tried also: http://jsfiddle.net/6o26j9e9/
The text is centred :D

```
body {
    background-color: #333;
    background: url('http://www.awesomeimages.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/4011001045_50701c52ff_b1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}

.border {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 1000px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    padding: 15px;
    display: table;
}

.circle {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    border-radius: 1000px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 70px;

}
```

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/6o26j9e9/1/